# How to disable pre-instantiating singletons on Spring?

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-boot, startup

I have followed [this blog post](http://dolszewski.com/spring/faster-spring-boot-startup/) to speed up the start-up time of my Spring Boot application. The post recommends adding the following to the main class:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
@ComponentScan(lazyInit = true)
static class LocalConfig {
}
```

I have ran my application with `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=local`. After starting my application, I have enabled the sampler in VisualVM and sampled the CPU usage of my application. The results are as follows:

[image: VisualVM sampler dump]

As you can observe, the singletons are still being pre-instantiated.

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to prevent pre-instantiation of singletons?

Comment: are all of your beans located inside config with lazyInit ?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker You mean are they between the curly brackets of the `LocalConfig` class? No, they are not.

Comment: no, I ask if lazyInit is applied to all beans in your context or you have some that may instantiate eagerly?

Comment: The config posted in that blog post is simply wrong (and explained wrong) as it doesn't override the configuration it **adds** to it and now you have 2 compont scans both scanning components one eager and one lazy. The lazy one is basically useless as it does the same as the other one. If you are really concerned about performance then disable the things you don't need and have profile specific configs/resources for that. You don't want a completely different config locally and in production as that is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker That's what I am asking actually. Does putting `@ComponentScan(lazyInit = true)` on a `LocalConfig` class result in lazy instantiation of all beans?

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please describe what would I need to do in order to accomplish lazy instantiation?

Comment: No as that will give you more problems then it solves. You don't want everything lazy as you will run into double proxy issues, missing bean instances etc. You are trying to use a Sherman tank to kill a fly...

Comment: it does, but you may have an eager bean that reference lazy bean, in that case lazy would be instantiated. thats why I ask if you have other eager beans outside your context

Comment: @M.Deinum Then can you tell me what should I do to decrease the start-up time of my Spring Boot application? 35 seconds start-up time is something more than fly by the way :)

Comment: Remove dependencies you don't need, don't let Spring do work it doesn't need to do. Also 35 seconds startup time doesn't have to be bad depending on how manu classes are scanned and what is started. Also switching OS might help (if you are on windows that is, in my experience), disable virus scanners etc.

Comment: as I observe , the preInstantiateSingletons() is called even for beans which lazyInit=true. I am looking for an answer as well.